# Python Strip Values in List?

Tags: python

I have a list of values in this format:

```
 ['11111-11111','22222-22222','33333-33333']
```

How do I strip the values in the list so I only have the first 5 numbers of each value in the list?

Looking for:
`['11111','22222','33333']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and slice each element in your list:

```
In [16]:
l=['11111-11111','22222-22222','33333-33333']
[x[:5] for x in l]

Out[16]:
['11111', '22222', '33333']
```

a call to `str.split` would work too:

```
In [17]:
l=['11111-11111','22222-22222','33333-33333']
[x.split('-')[0] for x in l]

Out[17]:
['11111', '22222', '33333']
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a very simple solution, it could be like that:

```
yourList = ['11111-11111','22222-22222','33333-33333']
newList = []
for item in yourList:
    newList.append(item[:5])
print(newList)
```

The output is `['11111', '22222', '33333']`

Comment: How is this simpler than @EdChum's answer?

Comment: It is just easier to understand if you are a beginner.

Comment: Thank you for showing me another way how to achieve the needed values. Your answer was helpful and appreciated!